# Pre populate select based on submitted value from the same select

Tags: php, forms, html-select

I have a select box which when selected reloads the page, how can I make sure the select still holds the selected value after the page reloads?

Thanks

Comment: Use php and HTML and your coding skills to do that :)

Comment: Wow I hadn't thought of that

Comment: You need to show what you have tried and what issues you are facing. SO is not here to code for you...Success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually thier is no way for catch the selected value after reloads the page. You can do it :

1. By Post
2. By Get
3. By Session
4. By cookie
5. Or BY ajax (Not reload the page)

You can selected option by this way value test . e.g.

```
if(isset($_POST['select']) && $_POST['select']==2){ echo "<option value='2' selected>Second</option>"; }
```

Same thing you can do with other PHP GLobal variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here already 2 options, there are probably many more:

1. Do not reload the entire page but only populate the dynamic elements that change using ajax (asynchronous calls).
2. Catch the selected value in PHP and set the selected `<option selected>` in the select list programatically

Succes!